# Is a free product of groups, possible on a commutative group with itself

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I have read on wikipedia that free product of two groups is not commutative unless one of the two groups is trivial. 
But suppose if take a commutative group and take free product with itself, isn't the resulting group is commutative?

Comment: No. For example, the free product of two copies of the free group on one generator is the free group on two generators.

Comment: @Qiaochu:But the reduced word will be in the same free group

Comment: $ab$ does not equal $ba$ within the free product $\langle a\rangle\ast\langle b\rangle$.

Comment: @arctic: Now I got it.

Answer (score 1):

In a free product, there is 'no commutation rule' for the elements, $a$ from the left copy of $G$ and $b$ from the right copy of $G$ (the group is, consequently, infinite in size, and non-commutative). (For simplicity, try doing this with $G$ a finite cyclic group, and imagine what the corresponding free product group looks like).

edit: by commutation rule, I mean something of the form $ba=a^jb^k$

Comment: Why do you say there is no commutator? There is such a commutator, and it is not equal to the identity, so the elements $a$ and $b$ do not commute.

Comment: I misspoke, technically, their is a commutator, $[a,b]=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$, but I was more referring to the idea that in all abelian, and many nice enough nonabelian groups, you have equations of the form $ba=a^jb^k$, but this need not occur in general (which is why the order of $\langle a,b \rangle$ need not be $|a|\cdot |b|$)